# Sobel algorithm without library, greyscale output

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, sobel

I'm trying to get this output [b&w positives and negatives and gray neutrals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYiLh.png)

But instead I'm getting this [B&W only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip7RO.png)

I'm not sure what to change about my code.

```cpp
Mat sobelX(const cv::Mat &m){
    Mat im = m.clone();
    int gx, mag;

    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m.cols; 
            //find x gradient
            gx = m.at<uchar>(i-1, j-1)
                + 2*m.at<uchar>(i, j-1)
                + m.at<uchar>(i+1, j-1)
                - m.at<uchar>(i-1, j+1)
                - 2*m.at<uchar>(i, j+1)
                - m.at<uchar>(i+1, j+1);

            mag = sqrt(gx*gx);

            if (mag < 0) {
                mag = 0;    //set to black
            }
            else if (mag > 255) {
                mag = 255;  //set to white
            }
            im.at<uchar>(i, j) = mag;
        }
    }
    return im;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the source image?

Comment: @Yunus Temurlenk The image which is already converted to grayscale is the Mat m that is passed in.

Comment: `gx` has range [-4,4] times range of `m.at<uchar>()` return. Do `m.at<uchar>()` returns need to be converted to `int` before anything else? `sqrt()` takes and returns a double, returns NaN for negative.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the “mag=sqrt(gx*gx)” line? Just taking the absolute value of gx?

Comment: Also, are you sure the output image is really black and white : ie has only 0 and 255 as pixel values?